# React DatePicker calendar showing behind table head

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, datepicker, z-index

I was using react datePicker and fixed-data-table-2 for my project. When I open the calendar, it shows behind table head. Here is the code for CSS file:

```
.ui-datepicker {
   z-index: 9999 !important;
}
.table{
   z-index: -1000  !important;
}
```

Here is React Code for DatePicker：

```
 <div className='ui-datepicker'>
           <DatePicker
                 selected={this.state.startDate}
                 selectsStart
                 startDate={this.state.startDate}
                 endDate={this.state.endDate}
                 onChange={this.onFilterStart}
            />
</div>
```

Here is shortcut code for Table:

```
<div className='table'>
     <Table
            rowHeight={50}
            rowsCount={tableData.getSize()}
            width={1000}
            maxHeight={1800}
            height={700}
            groupHeaderHeight={30}
            headerHeight={50}
            onColumnResizeEndCallback={this.resizeEndCallback}
            isColumnResizing={false}
            >
            <ColumnGroup
                header={<Cell>Basic Info</Cell>}>
                <Column columnKey='menuTranslation'
                        header={ <SortHeaderCell
                                languageChosen={this.state.languageChosen}
                                onSortChange={this.sortChange}
                                sortDir={colSortDirs.foodName}>Food 
              Name</SortHeaderCell>}
                        isResizable={true}
                        width={columnWidths.foodName}
                        cell={<MyTextCell data={tableData}  
              field='menuTranslation' col="menuTranslation"  />}
                />
<div>
```

This is the image for the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try setting the z-index on `.react-datepicker-popper` instead of on datepicker. That's the className that react-date-picker uses on the popup it creates.

```
.react-datepicker-popper {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of Material-UI Paper component styles. Paper component has an overflow: hidden style, and by removing it works perfectly.

```
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
...
<Card>
<DayPickerInput  id="servdate" name="servdate"  dateFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
</Card>
```

In style set `.MuiCard-root{ overflow: visible!important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ends here and is using Material-UI Cards, I solved it by adding `z-index: 0 !important` to the CardHeader style (I noticed that it had `z-index: 3! important` by default using Chrome dev tools).

```
<CardHeader style={{zIndex: '0 !important'}}>
... 
</CardHeader>
```