# DatePicker calendar is hidden behind table header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-datepicker, react-data-grid

I'm trying to use `react-datepicker` in my `react-data-grid` filter but can't get to show the calendar on top, i tried to set the react popper [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412685/react-datepicker-calendar-showing-behind-table-head) among other configurations but nothing

```
.react-datepicker-popper {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

I'm new to web development, so this might be a dumb problem, anyway here is my code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dew-s69w1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ?